# Как узнать масштаб экрана с помощью python или pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как узнать масштаб экрана с помощью python или pyqt5. !!!Не разрешения!!!

Comment: DPI что ли? Для какой операционной системы?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите узнать и для чего вам это надо.

Comment: @S.Nick мне нужно это для последующего нормального масштабирования приложения

Comment: я не совсем понимаю что вы понимаете под  нормальным масштабированием приложения, попробуйте объяснить лучше, если предоставленный ответ не решил вашу проблему. И минимально-воспроизводимый пример, также улучшит понимание вашего вопроса.

Comment: @S.Nick при изменении масштаба в винде со 100% на 125% едет шрифт в qcombobox и верстка. я хотел получать масштаб и выдавать определенные стили для элементов, но теперь в ступоре из-за поехавшей верстки

Comment: О каком масштабировании вы говорите? У монитора есть только разрешение экрана, а у приложения свернутый/оконный/полноэкранный режимы отображения.  Приведите хотя бы пример строки с кодом, где вы меняете этот масштаб со 100% на 125%.

Comment: @Павел в винде можно поменять масштаб экрана из-за чего верстка может поехать. не могу прикрепить скрин

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @ZZaRRyaDD
Понял что вы имеете ввиду: https://viarum.ru/wp-content/uploads/mashtab-ekrana-windows-thumb.jpg
Это скрин.
Дальше я точно не смогу помочь, возможно кто-то подскажет с API. Или эти параметры можно получить из встроенных библиотек sys или os. Но лично я думаю - проблема не стоит выеденного яйца, никто этот масштаб не меняет, а по умолчанию всегда рекомендуется 100%.
Вне темы: ради интереса попробовал на своем приложении - перекосов не получил, возможно из-за того, что у меня геометрия задана не стилями. Хотя и стили шрифтов тоже не перекосило.

Answer (score 1):

Вот таким образом можно получить текущий DPI для мониторов.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
for screen in app.screens():
    dpi = screen.physicalDotsPerInch()
    print(f"Screen {screen.name()} DPI =", dpi)
app.quit()
```

```
Screen \\.\DISPLAY1 DPI = 141.58475185806762
Screen \\.\DISPLAY4 DPI = 99.60784313725489
```